# how i can hide Query string and *.aspx in url (c# , asp.net)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

please help me,i spend 1 day but yet i cant fix this

i need change address from:

```
http://localhost:61802/SHOP.aspx?Search=gg
```

to :

```
http://localhost:61802/SHOP/Search/gg
```

in web.config i have:

```
    <rule name="RewriteASPX" enabled="true">
      <match url="(.*)"  />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />

      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.aspx" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Rewrite Product ID" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^SHOP/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="SHOP.aspx?Search={R:1}"/>
    </rule>
```

Comment: Check this out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: `[0-9]+` will match one or more digits, yet your example parameter is `gg`. Also, you are not including `.aspx` after `SHOP`.

Comment: or just use MVC instead of webform all together

Comment: I agree with Steve. Add maybe webapi or mvc alongside the site?

Comment: @Davesoft I work to this project for 2 month, you say start Mvc project and do again

Comment: "alongside the site"    also, I'm not your boss ;)